# How to go about hosting files and reading them from iOS app

Tags: ios, file, hosting

I'm obviously aware that you can read files via URL and parse them as JSON etc. However, I've only ever done this with files that aren't hosted by me. I have a few files whose contents I need access to in my app, and I'm not sure how to go about this being that I want the files to be privately hosted, and not available with only the URL.

The way I've been going about this is creating a private GitHub repo and putting the files in that repo. But doing it this way, I have to put my GitHub personal authentication token in the app so it can access the files (the app is not deployed yet since I feel like this is not a secure way to do it).

Bit of a newbie here. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a normal backend server. But, you can also put files on Google Drive and make them availably using link for anyone. It should work.

For the backend:
0. Read resources nodejs.org or spring.io

1. Learn how to run a server
2. Learn how to add authentication
3. Learn how to add authorization
4. Put files on the server and require authorization.
5. Deploy the backend on public server.

Comment: Like I said "I want the files to be privately hosted, and not available with only the URL." I figured I would need a backend server, my question is *how* do I set something like that up for my use case?

Comment: If file is not available by URL, then it cannot be downloaded. Please edit the question because it's not clear.

Comment: The question at a high level: How can I host files privately that only I can access (via Swift)? Is that clearer? If your answer is still "You need a normal backend server." then that is my next question: Where can I learn how to set something like that up - a tutorial for beginners?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/ or http://spring.io/
1. Learn how to run a server
2. Learn how to add authentication
3. Learn how to add authorization
4. Put files on the server and require authorization.
5. Deploy the backend on public server.